# Call parent class function on derived class object (Java)

Tags: java, polymorphism, parent-child, equals

I have three classes:

**Parent**

```java
public class Parent {

    protected int parentValue;

    public Parent(int parentValue){
        this.parentValue = parentValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Parent){
            return ((Parent) obj).parentValue == parentValue;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Child**

```java
public class Child extends Parent{

    protected int childValue;

    public Child(int parentValue, int childValue){
        super(parentValue);
        this.childValue = childValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Child){
            Child child = (Child) obj;
            return child.childValue == childValue &&
                    child.parentValue == parentValue;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MiddleChild**

```java
public class MiddleChild extends Parent{

    public MiddleChild(int parentValue){
        super(parentValue);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof MiddleChild){
            return ((MiddleChild) obj).parentValue == parentValue;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to compare a `Child` and a `MiddleChild` using only their common properties (i.e., the properties defined in `Parent`). For example, if I create a `Parent` object with a `parentValue` of 7 and a `Child` (or `MiddleChild`) object with the same parentValue, as in the snippet below, `parent.equals(child)` evaluates to true. I would like to somehow call the `equals` function of the `Parent` object from the `Child` class. Is this even possible? I understand why the code below prints "failure"; is there an alternative method to access the `Parent.equals` function to compare `child` and `middle`? Obviously, the `super` object is not useful as I'm trying to compare two objects from some function external to both `Child` and `MiddleChild`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Parent parent = new Parent(7);
    Child child = new Child(7, 3);
    MiddleChild middle = new MiddleChild(7);

    if(parent.equals(middle)){
        System.out.println("Parent = Middle");
    }

    if(((Parent) child).equals(middle)){
        System.out.println("success!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("failure");
    }
}
```

The output of this snippet is

```
Parent = Middle
failure
```

Answer (score 0):

This idea seems to be a poor design to use equals() in this manner. You should really create a method in Parent called getParentValue(). Then you would compare using `if( child.getParenvValue() == middle.getParentValue() )`

Comment: Sure, that would be a useful solution if the classes are as simple as this demo. But in reality the classes I would like to compare are more complex. Also, it would be much easier to "future-proof" the comparison if I could call a function like `equals` rather than having to update a list of comparisons everywhere.

Comment: Then the equals() methods should check whether obj is an instanceof Parent.